# Not sure where this type error is coming from

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Im trying to test my code and all I get is a type error. I'm new to scala but as far as I can tell the ide is pointing at a bracket.

I've taken my function out of a main function (not sure what the purpose of that is, new to object oriented programming.) and I've tooled arount with my declarations

```
class FirstObject {
  def computeShippingCosts(weight: Double): Double = {
    var init: Double = 5.0
    var overW: Double = weight - 30.0
    if (weight >= 30) {
      var total: Double = init + (overW * .25)
    } else {
      var total: Double = 5.0
    }
  }
  println(computeShippingCosts(31.0))
}
```

I would expect the result of the println to be 5.25 but nothing prints other than the error so I don't know what to do.

Comment: yeah returned unit when double was expected

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't use `return` in Scala, it can cause some very odd errors. The last value in the function will be the result so there is no need for `return`.

You are getting an error because the last value is `val ...` and a declaration does not return a value (or rather it has the value `Unit`, which is the Scala equivalent of `void`).

It is also a good idea to avoid `if/else` if there is a function that can do the same thing. In this case you can use `max`:

```
def computeShippingCosts(weight: Double): Double =
  math.max(5, weight*.25 - 2.5)
```

I think this also expresses the logic better because it makes it clear that there is a computed cost with a minimum value. And this ensures that a heavier parcel is never cheaper than a lighter parcel, which is harder to guarantee with the original logic.

---

If you want to retain the original form of code, it looks like this:

```
def computeShippingCosts(weight: Double): Double = {
  val init: Double = 5
  val overW: Double = weight - 30.0

  if (weight >= 30) {
    init + (overW*.25)
  } else {
    5.0
  }
}
```

---

Andrey gives an alternative version which is more meaningful if you view the calculation as a base cost with a excess for overweight items:

```
def computeShippingCosts(weight: Double): Double =
  5 + 0.25*(weight - 30).max(0)
```

Comment: The `-2.5` in `math.max(5, weight * .25 - 2.5)` is weird, because it depends on all three parameters `5`,`30` and `0.25` in a not immediately obvious way (`-2.5 = 5 - 30 * 0.25`). Use `5 + 0.25 * (weight - 30).max(0)` instead, the `0` is a much better constant.